# Problem removing from Java-HashSet while implementing Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: java, set, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

in the following code I am trying to implement Kruskal's algorithm to compute the minimal spanning tree of a graph.

The problem is that removing sets from the connected components does not work properly and that the case if(!startSet.equals(endSet)) always seems to be executed.

Now the code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jgrapht.Graph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.AsSubgraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class mySpanningTree {
    
    //Receives a graph and computes a minimum spanning tree
    public static AsSubgraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> computeMST(Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph) {
        AsSubgraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> tree = new AsSubgraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge>(graph, graph.vertexSet(), new HashSet<DefaultWeightedEdge>());

        PriorityQueue<DefaultWeightedEdge> edgeQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(graph::getEdgeWeight));
        edgeQueue.addAll(graph.edgeSet());
        Set<Set<Integer>> connectedComponents = new HashSet<>();
        for(Integer i : graph.vertexSet()){
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(i);
            connectedComponents.add(set);
        }
        int n = tree.vertexSet().size() - 1;
        while (!edgeQueue.isEmpty() && tree.edgeSet().size() < n) {
            DefaultWeightedEdge edge = edgeQueue.poll();
            Integer start = graph.getEdgeSource(edge);
            Integer end = graph.getEdgeTarget(edge);
            Set<Integer> startSet =  null;
            Set<Integer> endSet = null;
            for(Set<Integer> set: connectedComponents){
                if(set.contains(start)){
                    startSet = set;
                }
                if(set.contains(end)){
                    endSet = set;
                }
            }
            if(!startSet.equals(endSet)){
                startSet.addAll(endSet);
                connectedComponents.remove(endSet);
                tree.addEdge(start, end, edge);
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        return tree;
    }
```

The idea of the code is to keep track of the connected components in a set. Whenever an edge connects two nodes from different connected components, I want to union the two connected components and store the result inside the set instead of the two components from before. Furthermore, the edge shall be added.
Whenever an edge has two endpoints in one and the same set, it shall not be added (since adding it would create a cycle).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `connectedComponents` is a mutable set, whose elements are also mutable sets. The problem is, that by destructively modifying the elements of `connectedComponents` without "notifying" the container, the container's data structures are silently corrupted.

Hash sets are managed data structures, that use an integer value (the `hashCode`) derived from the contents of their elements to guide where they put the object internally in their private data structures. This mechanism gives fast insertion and retrieval (usually in the order of `O(1)`). However, for this to work, the `hashCode` must not change while the object is present in the container.

In your code, the container is a `HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>` and the elements are `HashSet<Integer>` instances. For Java's sets, the hash code is computed based on the what the set currently contains. So, when you do

```java
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(i);
connectedComponents.add(set);
```

the `connectedComponents` container computes a hash code from `set` and uses that to determine a place to put the object into in its internal data structures. However, when you do

```java
startSet.addAll(endSet);
```

you **mutate** the contents of `startSet` which in turn causes its hash code to change. From `connectedComponent`'s perspective, the object is now "in the wrong place" in its internal data structures, and hence it is likely, that it will not be found again. The important thing here is, that data structure like `HashSet` are based on `equals` and `hashCode`, and for many data structures (including `HashSet`) those are based on the actual contents, not merely on object identity.

To address this problem, try removing the element set from `connectedComponents` before mutating it, and then add it back afterward:

```java
if(!startSet.equals(endSet)){
    connectedComponents.remove(startSet);  // Added back below ...
    connectedComponents.remove(endSet);
    startSet.addAll(endSet);
    connectedComponents.add(startSet);     // ... right here
    tree.addEdge(start, end, edge);
}
```

Alternatively, it might help to keep track of the element sets using a different container, like an `IdentityHashMap` (use whatever you like as the value). This would work here, since you do not need the container to track the element sets by their content (as `HashSet` implicitly does).

For example:

```java
IdentityHashMap<Set<Integer>, Object> connectedComponents = new IdentityHashMap<>();

...

for(Integer i : graph.vertexSet()){
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(i);
    connectedComponents.put(set, set);
}

...

for(Set<Integer> set: connectedComponents.keySet()) {
    ...
    if(set.contains(start)){
        startSet = set;
    }
    if(set.contains(end)){
        endSet = set;
    }
}

if(!startSet.equals(endSet)) {
    connectedComponents.remove(endSet);
    startSet.addAll(endSet);
    tree.addEdge(start, end, edge);
}
```

I am not sure right now, whether it should remain `!startSet.equals(endSet)` or whether you might want to use `startSet != endSet` with the modified code, though. The former version uses "deep equality" for the test (i.e., considers the actual contents the the sets involved) whereas the latter version works by object identity only, which I think would be more appropriate if you consider the `IdentityHashMap` route.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot. However, I do not yet understand exactly what you mean by "modifying the elements of connectedComponents without "notifying" the container". Why does the container need to be notified (especially since mutable set suggests that it would be apt to cope with changes to it)

Answer (score 1):

A typical implementation of Kruskal's algorithm uses [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this. With this data structure your code simplifies to the following:

```java
// Receives a graph and computes a minimum spanning tree
public static AsSubgraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> computeMST(Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph) {
    var tree = new AsSubgraph<>(graph, graph.vertexSet(), new HashSet<>());
    var edgeQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(graph::getEdgeWeight));
    edgeQueue.addAll(graph.edgeSet());
    DisjointSet connectedComponents = new DisjointSet(graph.vertexSet());
    int n = tree.vertexSet().size() - 1;
    
    while (!edgeQueue.isEmpty() && tree.edgeSet().size() < n) {
        DefaultWeightedEdge edge = edgeQueue.poll();
        Integer start = graph.getEdgeSource(edge);
        Integer end = graph.getEdgeTarget(edge);

        if (connectedComponents.findSet(start) != connectedComponents.findSet(end)) {
            connectedComponents.union(start, end);
            tree.addEdge(start, end, edge);
        }
    }
    
    return tree;
}
```

[*Introduction to Algorithms*, 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) by Thomas H. Cormen et al. devotes the whole Chapter 21 to the disjoint-set data structure. For a given set of elements, the data structure holds its subsets such that

1. every elements belongs to a subset held in the data structure and
2. subsets in the data structure do not intersect (i.e., disjoint).

Initially, all elements belong to its own, singleton, subset. The data structure allows to check if two elements belong to the same subset and to join subsets. This makes it ideal for graph algorithms: elements are vertices and subsets are connected components of the graph.

```java
public class DisjointSet {
    private Map<Integer, Entry> setEntries;
    
    private static class Entry {
        private Integer parent;
        private int rank;
    }
    
    // Creates a collection of singleton sets.
    public DisjointSet(Set<Integer> vertices) {
        setEntries = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (Integer vertex: vertices) {
            Entry r = new Entry();
            r.parent = vertex;
            r.rank = 0;
            setEntries.put(vertex, r);
        }
    }
    
    // Find the representative member of the subset containing the given element.
    public Integer findSet(Integer x) {
        Entry r = setEntries.get(x);
        
        if (r.parent != x) {
            r.parent = findSet(r.parent);
        }
        
        return r.parent;
    }
    
    // Joins two subsets containing the given elements.
    public void union(Integer x, Integer y) {
        link(findSet(x), findSet(y));
    }
    
    private void link(Integer x, Integer y) {
        Entry rx = setEntries.get(x);
        Entry ry = setEntries.get(y);
        
        if (rx.rank > ry.rank) {
            ry.parent = x;
        } else {
            rx.parent = y;
            
            if (rx.rank == ry.rank) {
                ry.rank++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain why your answer is **not** a link-only answer and why it is **not** more suitable as a comment (rather than an answer). I see that you have the _Informed_ badge and that you also have enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: Because if you aim to implement the state-of-the-art Kruskal's algorithm, this is the best answer.

But I will consider adding code, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score -2):

Here you must use from interfaces, befor create

```java
interface A {
    int set1 {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(i);
        return set;
    }
}

interface B extends A {
    Set<Integer> connectedComponents = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer i : graph.vertexSet()) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(i);
        connectedComponents.add(set);
    }
```

...etc. So you can solve problem step by step.

Comment: I understand that this is pseudo code (because it doesn't compile). Is that correct?